# How to get rid of similiar duplicates from MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL PHPMyAdmin database where I have accidentally appended two of the same parts. For me they are duplicates, but in terms of the actual data they are not. There are more columns in the `part_lists` table:

```
+-----+---------------------------+----------+
| id  |        Part   Name        | Quantity |
+-----+---------------------------+----------+
|  1  | Part A (1/4")             |     0    |
|  2  | Part B                    |     3    |
|  3  | Part D                    |     4    |
|  4  | Part E                    |     9    |
| ... | a lot of part names later |    ...   |
| 95  | Part A (1/4") (0 free)    |     4    |  <-- newly appended
| 96  | Part B (-1 free)          |     5    |  <-- newly appended
| 97  | Part C (10 free)          |     1    |  <-- newly appended
```

**Table Explanation:**

`id` is a `unique` number and is auto generated by the table. `Quantity` is the number of parts   in stock. `id#1` and `id#95` are the same part but `id#95` is the updated information - ie was meant to replace/update `id#1`. There should've never been the "`(0 free)`" string at the end of the part - and thus has to be removed. This is also the same case for `id#2` and `id#96`. `id#97` is a new part and I just need I get rid of the "`(10 free)`" string at the end. `id#3` and `id#4` are old parts that have not been updated, and thus should be left as they are.

**Question:**
The new parts that I have appended mostly (not all) have a "`([some number] free)`" string appended to the end of the `Part`. Sometimes these parts are unique (ie don't have a duplicate). **Q:** How would I get rid of the duplicates but make sure the information has been updated. **Q:** Could this be done with MySQL code? If not how would do I do this with bash!?

**Ideal Output:**

```
+-----+---------------------------+----------+
| id  |        Part   Name        | Quantity |
+-----+---------------------------+----------+
|  1  | Part A (1/4")             |     4    |  <-- Updated
|  2  | Part B                    |     5    |  <-- Updated 
|  3  | Part D                    |     4    |
|  4  | Part E                    |     9    |
| ... | a lot of part names later |    ...   |
| 95  | Part C                    |     1    |  <-- newly appended
```

The list will be relatively shorter as some of the information appended has updated entries from before.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a pain in MySQL.  Standard SQL would use `exists`:

```
delete t
    from t
    where partname like '%(% free)' and
          not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.name like concat(t.name, '(% free)'));
```

Or some similar logic.  But, MySQL doesn't allow you to reference the table where you are deleted.  So, I think you can find duplicates by using `substring_index()` in a `join` and then deleting the duplicate rows.  First, though, you want to update the values:

```
update t join
       t tfirst
       on tfirst.id < t.id and
          substring_index(t.partname, ' (', 1) = tfirst.partname and
          t.partname like '% (% free)'
    set tfirst.quantity = tfirst.quantity + t.quantity;
```

Note that this formulation only works for one duplicate.  If there are more than one, then an arbitrary one will be chosen for the update.

Then you can delete the duplicates:

```
delete t
    from t join
         t tfirst
         on tfirst.id < t.id and
            substring_index(t.partname, ' (', 1) = tfirst.partname and
            t.partname like '% (% free)';
```

Then, you want to update the partnames that are remaining "c" record:

```
update t
    set partname = substring_index(t.partname, ' (', 1)
    where t.partname like '% (% free)';
```